# Which accuracy score to use for the Mean Decrease Accuracy with the scikit RandomForestClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, scikit-learn, classification

I've been running the implementation the '**Mean Decrease Accuracy**' measure that is shown on this [website](http://blog.datadive.net/selecting-good-features-part-iii-random-forests/):

In the example the author is using the random forest regressor `RandomForestRegressor`, but I am using the random forest classifier `RandomForestClassifier`. Thus, my question is, if I should also use the `r2_score` for measuring accuracy or if I should switch to classic accuracy `accuracy_score` or matthews correlation coefficient `matthews_corrcoef`?.

Does anybody here if I should switch or not. And why?

Thanks for any help!

---

Here is the code from the website in case you are too lazy to click :)

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import ShuffleSplit
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from collections import defaultdict

X = boston["data"]
Y = boston["target"]

rf = RandomForestRegressor()
scores = defaultdict(list)

#crossvalidate the scores on a number of different random splits of the data
for train_idx, test_idx in ShuffleSplit(len(X), 100, .3):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_idx], X[test_idx]
    Y_train, Y_test = Y[train_idx], Y[test_idx]
    r = rf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    acc = r2_score(Y_test, rf.predict(X_test))
    for i in range(X.shape[1]):
        X_t = X_test.copy()
        np.random.shuffle(X_t[:, i])
        shuff_acc = r2_score(Y_test, rf.predict(X_t))
        scores[names[i]].append((acc-shuff_acc)/acc)
print "Features sorted by their score:"
print sorted([(round(np.mean(score), 4), feat) for
              feat, score in scores.items()], reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`r2_score` is for regression (continuous response variable), whereas classic classification (discrete categorical variable) metrics such like `accuracy_score` and `f1_score` `roc_auc` (the last two are most appropriate if you have unbalanced y-labels) are right choices for your task.

Random shuffling each features in the input data matrix and measuring the decline in these classification metrics sounds like a valid approach to rank feature importances.

Comment: Hi @Jianxun Li, thanks for the explanation. So you would not recommend the MCC? If you talk about unbalanced y-labels, you mean that cases of correct classifications are unevenly distributed. Also I am not sure, why it is calculated this (normalized) way: `(acc-shuff_acc)/acc` instead of just `acc-shuff_acc`. Do you know what the advantage is?

Comment: @dmeu Sorry that I forgot to include `MCC` in the post. I think it's equally as good as other classification metrics derived from confusion matrix.

Comment: Thanks @Jianxun Li!  Do you have any thoughts on the followup questions in the first comment?

Comment: @dmeu it looks like OK to just use the unnormalized decline in accuracy for this particular model. Normalization might be crucial if you would like to compare feature importances in different models across different datasets.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense - yes, as soon I'd like to start comparing I have to use the normalized mean decrease.